# DFA for $\{0^m1^n \mid m+n \text{ is even}\}$

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

How do I construct a DFA for the language $\{0^m1^n \mid m+n \text{ is even}\}$? The corresponding regular expression is
$(00)^*(11)^* + (00)^*0(11)^*1$.

Comment: It's worth noting that the language $L$ is not the same as that described by your r.e.

Comment: I thought that this the correct R.E for given L.

Comment: You can build a four/five-state FA for the language by focussing on states: what should the automaton keep track of during the computation. For me that are two binary components. (A) Have we already seen the letter $1$? If so we accept only $1$'s. (B) Keep track of the length $m+n$ of the string modulo 2. When combining (A) and (B) we have 2x2=4 states. If you want a deterministic automaton you should add a garbage state where we end after reading another $0$ after reading a $1$.

Answer (score 1):

This language can be described as 'zero or more zeroes followed by zero ore more ones, where if the number of zeroes is even, so are the number of ones, and vice versa'.

So you just need to keep track of the parity of both the zeroes and ones, and if they match, accept.

[image]

Comment: can you describe how you came to this solution and how to tackle problems like these.

Comment: @user9600686 It's just the pattern I recognized in the regex - I can't really explain how to do that other than to practice. The systematic method for finding NFA's for regular expressions is fairly straightforward, turning them into a DFA is not (or at least very laborious).

Comment: In general writing DFA for a problem involves combining together various different "patterns" (exactly the same to how writing an algorithm involves combining together various different sub-routines). One way to test your knowledge on this "sub-routine" is to try to extend this to other similar problems --- say a DFA for the language $L = \{0^n1^m | m + 2n \equiv 0\bmod 3\}$, or $L = \{0^n1^m \mid n \equiv 1\bmod 2\land m\equiv 0\bmod 5\}$. These should be relatively simple to write if you "recognize the pattern" that @orlp is using in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to construct a DFA for your language is your product construction.

The starting point is a DFA for $0^*1^*$ (above) and one for all strings of even length (below):

[[image: DFA for <span class=]$0^*1^*$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRoHe.png)

[image: DFA for even-length strings]

Applying the product construction, we get a DFA for the intersection:

[image: DFA for the intersection]

We can improve on this DFA slightly by merging the two states on the right:

[image: Minimal DFA]

This is the minimal DFA for the language. To show this, it is enough to show that two different accepting states are needed, and that three different non-accepting states are needed.

We need two different accepting states due to the words $\epsilon$ and $01$: while $00$ is in the language, $0100$ isn't.

We need three different rejecting states due to the words $0,1,10$: while $00$ is in the language, $10$ and $100$ aren't; and while $11$ is in the language, $101$ isn't.